# How to compile a Gemma 7b TFLite model for MediaPipe?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, large-language-model, tflite, gemma

I tried `gemma-2b-it-gpu-int4` and `gemma-2b-it-cpu-int4` on my phone. I'd like to test a `gemma-7b-it-gpu-int4` because 2b was extremely snappy and MLC-LLM could handle a 7b Llama2 so I assume Gemma 7b will fit too.

https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/genai/llm_inference#models
offers 4 2b Gamma out of the box downloadable from Kaggle:

- gemma-2b-it-cpu-int4: Gemma 4-bit model with CPU compatibility.
- gemma-2b-it-cpu-int8: Gemma 8-bit model with CPU compatibility.
- gemma-2b-it-gpu-int4: Gemma 4-bit model with GPU compatibility.
- gemma-2b-it-gpu-int8: Gemma 8-bit model with GPU compatibility.

https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/genai/llm_inference#convert-model shows a converter, but that has a `model_type` parameter with values `{"PHI_2", "FALCON_RW_1B", "STABLELM_4E1T_3B", "GEMMA_2B"}`. Something is missing.

What do I do for 7b Gemma? Looks like I can start off of a PyTorch Gemma 7b bin, but then what should be the converter parameters, especially the `model_type` so I can end up with a GPU or CPU model which is 4 bit quantized and 16 bit floating point precision?

Comment: Or is there a path with https://github.com/google/gemma.cpp/ to Android?

Comment: Right now the converter script does not offer int4 Post Training Quantization. You can do only int8 with that script. You see options for int4 for Gemma but they did a QAT (quantization aware training) run for it where they specifically trained the model to work with a blend of int 4 / int 8 (but mostly int 4) parameters. They are working on int4 PTQ where the model can keep its accuracy.

Comment: @Farmaker Thanks for the info. The int8 unfortunately would mean it could not fit into memory as a 7b i4f16 Llama2. If there was an int4, it could be run on a phone, and that's my goal!